# Is there a way to create a flat button in Nativescript Android application?

Tags: android, material-design, nativescript

Is there an easy way to get rid of the default shadow of raised buttons in Nativescript Android application? I'm trying to create a subtle button but can't find a way to make the button appear flat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get rid of the native button default, you can try setting `border-width: 1;` on the style.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.

Comment: It is a bit long to explain (on phone now) but it has to deal with Android drawables and how NS allows devs to use css to style widgets. So setting the border width causes the border to override the buttons native default (raised shadow).

Answer (score 1):

Additionally `android-elevation: 0;` can be added for android.